# simple jQuery modal popup not showing on gridview button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have used **bPopup** as jquery plugin.link is :http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Lightweight-jQuery-Modal-Popup-Plugin-bPopup.html

this is the gridview with a button field.

```
              <asp:GridView ID="gvwData" runat="server" 
                   AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="preview">
                        <ItemTemplate>                              
                          **<asp:Button id="mybutton" runat="server" Text="click"/>**
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                    <AlternatingRowStyle Width="220px" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

This is the JavaScript Function :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).on("click", "[id*=mybutton]", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();     

          **$('#elementtopopup').bPopup();**

 });  (jQuery);


</script>
```

**$('#elementtopopup').bPopup()** not showing. Below is a screenshot of the error I'm getting.

[Screenshot of the console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X6lk.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your selector is wrong for the button, should be:

```
$(document).on("click", "[id$='mybutton']", function(e) {
    // code
});
```

Web forms suffixes the id with your specified id rather than prefixes it which your selector is looking for.

Comment: yeah..i changed that also.and meantime i put all the codes relevant to the pop up(div,scripts) at the bottom of the page.instead using the id of the button i used CssClass,finally it worked. Thanks for the help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the plugin to the bottom of your page

```
<script src="jquery.bpopup-0.8.0.min.js"></script>//change it to the path of the js file
```

Comment: do you have jquery.bpopup-0.8.0.min.js on your sistem?

Comment: yes.
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.bpopup.min.js"></script>

Comment: does the file load properly ,what return code does it have?

Comment: I tired it with a button outside the grid.then it worked.